# Am I using the 'static' keyword correctly?

Tags: java, static, non-static

I am trying to call a class' (Lord.java) method from the main method. When I first tried this Eclipse threw errors about calling non-static methods from a static method. I then changed all the fields/methods to static that Eclipse recommended, and this has fixed the issue. I know there are few situations where static should be used and I am uncertain as to whether I've used the keyword correctly in my code. If not, how can I rewrite this without it?

**Main.java**

```
package mainPackage;


public class Main {


static Lord Robert = new Lord(15, 'a');
Lord Renly = new Lord(-5, 'b');
Lord Stannis = new Lord(30, 'b');
Lord Oberyn = new Lord(-60, 'b');
Lord Eddard = new Lord(0, 'a');
Lord Tywin = new Lord(90, 'a');


//Instantiatation ends
int fiefs;

public static void main (String args[]) {
    Robert.giveFief();
    System.out.print(Robert.relationship);
}
}
```

**Lord.java**

```
package mainPackage;

public class Lord {

    protected static int relationship;
    protected char clique;

    public Lord(int a, char b) {
        relationship = a;
        char clique = b;
    }


    public static int giveFief() {
        relationship +=10;
        return relationship;

    }
    }
```

Comment: Why would you like your `relationship` to be `static` ? If you remove that, you don't need Robert to be `static`. Plus, you should use getters to access your `relationship` field ! Getters and setters forever

Comment: I removed the `static` keyword from `relationship` and `giveFief()`, however it still requires Robert to be static. Is this correct usage?

Comment: @Lutzi There is no benefit to getters and setters if you aren't performing any checks on the values.

Comment: I think you have to remove the `static` from `public static int giveFief()` too. About getters and setters, I think it's just the best way to use fields. Fields must always be private, and use getters and setters. Some people will claim that there is no benefit, but it widely avoid problem. I'm just quoting a professional Java programmer who has a lot of practice, and it seems to be a good advice. Still, you can try not to use getters and setters, but at the some point you'll have problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `static` keyword means that you do not require an instance of this type to use a specific field or method.  The *inverse* of that is that if you do have a field that is declared `static`, then *every* instance will have the same value.

In that light, you have a few major problems:

- `relationship` will be set to 90 for all instances of `Lord`s.  This is obviously not what you want.
- In `Main`, you can only interact with `Robert` inside of `main` since that's the only variable you've declared that doesn't require an instance of `Main` to use.

The first issue is straightforward to fix - remove `static` from that field.  The second one is just as straightforward - remove `static` from the field *and* move all of your instantiation statements inside of the `main` method.